# how to use jquery to display images from a json array in a php file

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a php file that creates a json array for my images and corresponding text:

```
<?php
$images = array(
"Image 1" => array("name" => "Image 1", 
            "price" => "$299", 
            "desc" => "Description 1",
            "image" =>"images/image1.jpg"),
"Image 2"   => array("name" => "Image 2", 
            "price" => "$199", 
            "desc" => "Description 2",
            "image" => "images/image2.jpg"),
"Image 6"   => array("name" => "Image 6", 
            "price" => "$199", 
            "desc" => "Description 6",
            "image" => "images/image6.jpg")
);

echo json_encode($images);
```

and my jQuery function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $div = $("#thumbs");
$.getJSON('getProducts.php', function(data) {
    jQuery.each(data, function(key, val){
        $("<img />").attr("src", val).appendTo($div);
    });
});
});
```

When I run this, I only get broken image links. Firebug shows:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/wpdhw8/%5Bobject%20Object%5D"
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Oh, and I've moved the images to the root so I took out the 'images/' from the filename.

And to answer my own question, I added a caption to the image by adding the line:

```
$($div).append('<p>' + val.name + '</p>');
```

right under:

```
$("<img />").attr("src", val.image).appendTo($div);
```

I really appreciate the help on this site! Thank-you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
$.getJSON('getProducts.php', function(data) {
    jQuery.each(data, function(key, val){
        $("<img />").attr("src", val.image).appendTo($div);
    });
});
```

Each `val` is an object like:

```
{ name: "Image 1",
  price: "$299",
  desc: "Description 1",
  image: "images/image1.jpg"
}
```

Comment: You can also use `$('<img />', {src: val.image})`

Comment: And if I want to add the name below the image would I use $("<p>").attr("", val.name).appendTo($div);   I tried it and it's not working.

Comment: Use `val.name` to get the name, and insert it where you want in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

the line

```
$("<img />").attr("src", val).appendTo($div);
```

should be

```
$div.append('<img src="'+val+'" />');
```

**EDIT**

oops misread it

for either line change `val` to `val.image`

Comment: personally I would not use `$` in variable names in javascript but I wanted to use the code you are using

Comment: The $div.append gets me the exact same result.

Comment: @GeekNum88: `$` is a completely valid character for variable names in JavaScript. Some people (me included) prefix variables that contain jQuery objects with the dollar sign to make them easier to identify.

Comment: @Blender I agree its completely valid - personally I would not use `$` in a variable name

Answer (score 0):

Your url 'getProducts.php' is not correct

Perhaps it needs to be '/getProducts.php' or have and other part in it ..
From your how url remove domain part...

```
http://localhost.local/getProducts.php => /getProducts.php
```

404 Not found - means that the page you have set cant be found..

Comment: the php file is in the root. I tried changing the single quotes to double quotes. No change. I also tried with the /getproducts.php. Same problem.

Comment: on your browser can you open that page localhost/getProducts.php ?